# Why doesn't the JDialog constructor center itself over the specified owner component?

Tags: java, swing, centering, jdialog

Using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) `JDialog` constructor, where I specify the owning `JFrame` instance, I find that the `JDialog` is not centered over it's owner component. Instead, it appears in the top-left corner. In order to get this to work, I must specify the owner component in the `setLocationRelativeTo` method.

Why is this?

**Work Environment:**

- Dual monitors
- Windows XP OS
- JDK 1.6.0_29

Note that for the `JFrame` instance, I use `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`.

Comment: and if you set `setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);` instead of `setModal(true)` what's happened ???,

Comment: @mKorbel, Doesn't change a thing..

Comment: how are plugged monitors 1) HW-GPU with two DVI, 2) HW-GPU with VGA and DVI, 3) on-board-GPU with two DVI, 2) on-board-GPU with VGA and DVI, 5) professional GPU with more than one GPU cores, 6) two or more GPU chained in some of SLI modes, 7) un-healt drivers, very old and instaled GPU drivers long time ago, 8) another ZOO

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: _since centering components is so commonplace_ hmm, not entirely convinced that it is: a well-behaved ui will open the dialog at a location which is most convenient for the user. Typically, that's where it was located when the user closed it last. So choosing a location on opening is appropriate only at the very first open action (the very first time the app the run). All others would use a _stored_ location

Answer (score 3):

`JDialog` is very general I think. If you want quick ways to pop a general dialog box then look at [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html). It has methods to easily create a centred `JDialog` component or immediately pop up a blocking dialog window.

e.g.

```
JDialog dialog = new JOptionPane("message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE)
    .createDialog(jFrameOwner, "window title");
```

Though you probably really want to look at the `JOptionPane.showXxxDialog` static methods. Very useful and convenient.

And you may wish to take a look at the [dialog tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). All the dialogs produced by the java web start application can be produced using the `JOptionPane` class.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a design decision. Sometimes you want to give the dialog a reference to it's parent, without to center the location over it.

Comment: You are completely right. I suppose that's just a poor assumption on my part. But you would think since centering components is so commonplace, that they would provide us with a convenience constructor, you know? :D

Comment: @Крысa: Yes, it had mostly been less to code if it centered the dialog by default, and set the position with a method if needed.

Comment: @Крысa: Maybe it's positioned as OS default or Look-and-Feel default if not `setLocationRelativeTo()` is called. (e.g. top center)

Comment: _Maybe it's positioned as OS default or Look-and-Feel default_ - playing guessing games or is it what you are seeing in your context? On win it doesn't, always in top leading corner of screen independent on LAF